# Irreducible projective varieties and morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth and irreducible projective curve, and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ a morphism of varieties: then $f$ is either constant or surjective. I am trying to prove this in an elementary way (I don't know about schemes, and I cannot use the notion of completeness).

I think it should be possible to cover $\mathbb{P}^1$ with two affine open sets $U,V$ both isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ and then exploit the fact that the functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$ have to be constant but I cannot seem how to patch this up and how it relates to surjectivity.

Comment: You're on the right track. Assume it's not surjective and choose your cover appropriately.

Comment: I think that is not that easy. Can you use Riemann-Roch theorem?

Comment: Yes I can use it.

Comment: Have I lost it? I think there are more general statements of this form where you need something fancier, but I think this is much easier...

Comment: Say two points  $P, Q \in \mathbb{P}^1$ are in the image of $f$, then either $U$ or $V$ contains both of them but this violates the fact that $f$ should be constant on $U$ and $V$. So if $f$ is not surjective it is constant. In this way I prove that it can only take one value, but I am missing a way to draw conclusions from one point that is $not$ in the image of $f$.

Comment: I mean how can I put myself in the position of using the above argument? Is it trivial that the image of $f$ has to be a finite set of point?

Comment: If $f$ misses a point, WLOG take that point to be the point at infinity, so that $im(f) \subset U$. But then $f$ is a map to $\mathbb{A}^1$, so must be constant.

I'm worried I'm saying something wrong though...been out of the game too long.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not convinced. In your setting $f$ is just a map to $im(f)$ the way I see it.

Comment: @Karl : there is nothing wrong with this argument I think. We started with a map $C \to \Bbb P^1$. By hypothesis $\infty$ is not in the image, so it factors by a map $C \to \Bbb A^1$. By what you already know this map is constant, so the original map was constant as well.

Comment: Hi Nicolas. Why can it not take another value on the point $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus U$? That's included in $V$ and surely $U$ and $V$ overlap but why does $f$ have to agree on this overlap in the codomain?

Comment: Is it perhaps by my argument about the 2 points? That might work.

Comment: @Karl That doesn't even make sense. The morphism can't take values on $\Bbb{P}^1\setminus U$, since $\Bbb{P}^1$ is the codomain, not the domain. And by assumption $\Bbb{P}^1\setminus U$ is not in the image of the morphism, so the morphism doesn't take on that value either.

Comment: @jgon So basically just proving it's constant from $X$ to $U$ means it's constant as a map from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: @Karl Yes, precisely. You can think of it as factoring the map $X\to U\hookrightarrow \Bbb{P}^1$. The fact that the first map is constant implies that the overall map is constant.